# Editing shadow root using adopted stylesheets

Tags: javascript, css, reactjs

I'm trying to edit a div in the shadow root of another div. Here's my html:

```
<active-overlay>
    #shadow-root
    <div class="modal"></div>
    #shadow-root
    <div class="grid"></div>
    <div> 
        <div class="form-wrapper"></div>
    </div>
</active-overlay>
```

How can I edit the CSS for the div with class modal using adoptedStyleSheets and old way so that it's supported in Chrome and old versions of Safari?